# Row_number not showing 1 rank

Tags: sql

I am using the below code to get the rank but not able to see the 1st rank.  I am getting the results 2 and 3.

```
 Select BPMDate,Tenor,TenorStartDays,TenorEndDays,NominalTransacted,
   SumofNominalRate,AverageRate,VWAR,rw,SortOrder
 FROM 
 (
SELECT case_id,created_date BPMDate,tenor Tenor,tenor_start_days TenorStartDays,
   tenor_end_days TenorEndDays
  ,nominal_transacted NominalTransacted,sum_of_nominal_rates SumofNominalRate
  ,average_rate AverageRate,vmar VWAR
 ,Case when tenor='O/N' Then 1 when tenor='1W' Then 2 when tenor='1M' Then 3 
when tenor='3M' Then 4 
    when tenor='6M' Then 5 when tenor='1Y' Then 6 Else 7 End SortOrder,
    row_number() over ( partition by tenor order by created_date desc ) rw
    From    table1
    Where   df_type = 'DF1' and to_date(created_date) >= '2020-10-13' and
     to_date(created_date) <= '2020-10-13'
     ) ard
    inner join 
    (
    select case_id,case_status from  table2
    where case_status='Completed') ad
    on ard.case_id=ad.case_id
    order by sortorder
```

The column rw is beginning from 2 instead 1

thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

I think you are filtering it out when you join to ad , If you just select the sub query I think you will be able to see it.

Comment: yeah correct but those records are not meeting the condition which is  mentioned in the second table. Any suggestions how to overcome this? Thank you.

Comment: @viresh then you have to bring it to your first select , you have to get rid of subquery , try to rewrite your code by transferring sub-query to a join to the rest of code